# Can UXExchange be redirected here?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, merge

The UXExchange site still just says that it is disabled. I think it would be better to redirect them to UX.SE, or at least put a link to this site from there. Is anything like that in the plans?

Comment: Try flushing your DNS cache.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed now.  The following URLs all redirect correctly:

- http://uxexchange.com
- http://www.uxexchange.com
- http://uxexchange.stackexchange.com

I initially missed the last two.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I was using uxexchange.com. And I was checking it explicitly for the people that didn't already have accounts on this site. As you can see by my points total (which has not been updated post-merge), I was already on this site.

Comment: @Charles Hm, very odd.  Is it still happening?

Comment: uxexchange.com doesn't seem to be redirecting anywhere: "The website "www.uxexchange.com" has been disabled" - and there's an email contact form at Fogcreek.

Comment: @PhillipW @Charles ahh, it's the "www" part.  We redirected `uxexchange.com` but not `www.uxexchange.com`.  Fixing this now

Comment: Fixed now. Thanks.

Comment: Note: It seems like the `uxexchange.com` domain has since been acquired by someone else. (The `uxexchange.stackexchange.com` URL also currently doesn't redirect as mentioned – I'm not sure it's worth maintaining, since it was never a valid URL for the site, as far as I know.)

Answer (score 2):

I only got here from the old UXExchange url. I've just tested it and it redirects fine for me. Try clearing your browsers cache.

Comment: I've tried on multiple computers, multiple browsers (including those that I had never visited UXExchange on before) and cleared cache on each and I am still getting the "disabled" message.